# What's the word for fading speech?

Tags: word-usage

Some public speakers (lecturers) become quieter as they run out of air toward the end of a sentence.  The result is something like "The important thing we learned is mumble" (inaudible).
I need to search for solutions, perhaps an automatic level or gain control. But I can't figure out what to search for, and haven't found anything helpful yet. This is fairly common in technical lectures, so surely the problem is discussed somewhere.
What is this called?  "Swallowing words" doesn't seem quite right.

Comment: It seems unlikely that there is a specific word for this in English other than those you've already mentioned "fading", "mumbling".  Is there a word for it in your native language? The technical  point of "making the loud parts quiter so you can boost the quiet parts" is called "dynamic range compression"

Comment: The expression that I have heard for this effect is to say that the voice "trails off".

Comment: In my experience, a reduction of volume toward the end of a sentence in normal.  https://voiceandspeech.com/trailing-off/#:~:text=It%20happens%20when%20the%20speaker,and%20a%20loss%20of%20impact. I think that it's unlikely that  you will find a technical solution to this problem at the moment. Smartphones incorporate features that handle this problem well, but PA systems are not, generally, smart enough. For the time being, the best approach is to play back the worst examples to the speaker, and encourage them to maintain an (unnaturally) even volume throughout every sentence.

Comment: As others have said, this behavior is normal. It's only good speakers who have learned NOT to do this.  I do a lot of audio work for presentations/online learning and this is one of the five most common problems I hear. I always recommend what @JavaLatte has said. It feels unnatural at first but you do get used to it. I also agree that "trailing off" is the best way to describe it.

Answer (score 1):

The expression you're looking for is "*running out of breath*".

When speaking, it is important to pause to *draw breath*. When you don't, you 'run out of breath'.

For example:

> He spoke for so long without a pause that he ran out of breath.

It is important not to confuse it with simply "out of breath", which is usually due to a raised heart rate or some other medical condition like asthma.

Comment: It's not generally about running out of breath. It is normal for the volume of speech to decline throughout a sentence: we don't notice it, because we perceive it as normal. When you do sound recording, the instruments show that it happens even on short sentences, long before people run out of breath. it's a particular problem for public speakers, especially ones who use powerpoint: volume declines even more as they prepare to move to the next slide.

Comment: @JavaLatte I agree that a voice "trailing off" as you mentioned in a comment is not always about running out of breath. However, if you read the OP it specifically refers to running out of "air". "Breath" is the idiomatic way to refer to shortage of 'air' when speaking.

Comment: I agree that that's the OP's analysis of the situation, but I don't agree with that analysis.

Comment: @JavaLatte Well this question fits the answer as posed, which is why I believe it to be correct. I have no problem understanding the question. A voice trailing off can be because of a distraction, or any number of other reasons. The OP was quite specific. If you'd like to give you answer to a question that hasn't been asked, there is the provision within the site rules to post your own question and answer it, Q&A style.